# Asp.net MVC-4 Basic button click count page - Beginner

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Using mvc-4 basic template I am creating a view with button a HTML button. Which upon being clicked will display. How many times this button has been clicked.

Created Model

**ButtonTest.cs**

```
namespace testmvc4basic.Models
{
    public class ButtonTest
    {
        public int clickCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Created View
**Strongly typed View**

```
@model testmvc4basic.Models.ButtonTest

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ButtonTest";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

### ButtonTest

---

While Attempting to create Controller, with the dialog
[image]

**I get unsupported context type. What Am I missing, please ?**

Comment: Are you using the Entity Framework? If not, switch to another template, like "Empty controller"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have created Database Context, and needed context not appear in list in add controller dialog - try to build solution, and try to add controller again, your model class should appear.
2. If you don't have Database context, and you still want to add controller using same template you need to create Database context class inherited from DbContext or Object context.
3. Or if you don't want to use context you should choose another template without specifying any context